# Year of print of an edition of Torah

Tags: books-generally

Sorry if this is off topic. I got an edition of Torah, printed in London, and which has the Hebrew text accompanied by translation to German, printed in gothic characters. The year of the edition is written as follows:

"נדפס בעיר הבירה לונדן בשנת אשרי אדם מצא
חכמה ואדם יפיק תבונה לפ''ק"

I attach the image of the front page. Could someone help to determine its year of print? Thank you, and again sorry if this is off topic.

[image]

Comment: Usually you add up the gematria of the letters marked with a supralinear dot

Answer (score 5):

Although usually one would add up the letters that have a dot on top. However in this case that would put the year in the future. Therefore, it looks like you add up the letters, not counting the ones with a dot on top.

This adds up to 596. The letters at the end of לפ״ק indicates that it’s only counting the smaller number not the thousands (פרט קטן). It is safe to assume it is in the 5,000’s so it would be the year 5,596 which corresponds to 1836

Comment: Marginally more likely than the future is the past 4878

Comment: That’s more than 300 years before the printing press was invented

Comment: And more than 800 years before time machines were